# handle 503 error with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor, gridfs

I´m using `gridfs` to store images in a `mongoDB`. I have an issue when I update images in the background and want to update them on the screen when finished uploading. I fire an event when I have an image document stored in my mongoDB and then I update the screen. It looks like the document is created while uploading the image because if I do it this way, my image is broken with a `503 error` (service not available). When I refresh the page the image appears on the screen.

I believe the problem is that I try to get the image when it is still uploading. I would like to do a `$.get(imagesURL)` and catch the 503 error but I don't know how to do this. If I could catch the error I could do a loop and wait until its uploaded.

Maybe you guys also have better solutions or know how to catch a 503 error using jquery?
I use a normal `file input field` for the image

(part of my Template Event in `meteorjs`)

```
'change #avatarForm': function (event) {
        FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function (file) {
            Images.insert(file, function (err, fileObj) {
                if (err) {
                    // handle error
                } else {
                    // handle success depending what you need to do
                    var userId = Meteor.userId();
                    var imagesURL = {
                        "profile.image": "/cfs/files/images/" + fileObj._id
                    };
                    Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: imagesURL});

                    function checkAvatar() {
                        $.get(imagesURL)
                            .complete(function () {
                                Session.set("registerAvatar", "/cfs/files/images/" + fileObj._id);
                            }).onerror(function () {
                                console.log("but still uploading");
                                checkAvatar();
                            });
                        console.log("image saved!");
                    }
                    checkAvatar();
                }
            });
        });
    },
```

my code should only fire the new image on the screen (url is set as SessionVar) when the image is completed but its not working.

this is my exact error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. The pattern is to set a template helper with a reactive data source - in this case, `Meteor.user()`. When `Meteor.user()` changes, the template helper will render out the new data without you having to fetch any data manually:

```
<template name="test">

    <div>Profile Image:</div>
    {{#if profileImage}}
    <div><img src="{{profileImage}}"></div>
    {{/if}}

</template>

Template.test.events({

  'change #avatarForm': function(event) {
    FS.Utility.eachFile(event, function(file) {
      Images.insert(file, function(err, fileObj) {
        if (err) {
          // handle error
        } else {
          // handle success depending what you need to do
          var userId = Meteor.userId();
          var profileImage = {
            "profile.image.url": fileObj.url(),
            "profile.image.id": fileObj._id
          };
          Meteor.users.update(userId, {
            $set: profileImage
          });
        }
      });
    });
  },

});

Template.test.helpers({
  profileImage: function () {
    return Meteor.user().profile.image.url;
  }
});
```